# N- and P-channel MOSFETs in series

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet

I'm currently trying to build a soldering station. Everybody on the internet uses AC-voltage for that, but I haven't really found the reason for that. So I thought "Well, let's build one and see if it works with DC as well".

At first I wanted to switch the heater element with a single MOSFET, but unfortunately the thermoelement shares a common ground with the heater element. That's why I thought about this design, which is quite similar to an H-bridge. As far as I understand it should do a good job of isolating the SS_GND- and SS_Heater-Pins when I turn Q1 and Q2 off, right?

I'm not too experienced with this type of electronics, so I thought it's better if I ask someone else first.

Thanks for your help!

[image: Current design]

Comment: Why do you need to switch the heater ground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want Q2 to be conducting when IC_P1 is high, you need to wire the output of OK1 to pull Q2's gate to ground, not high as you have it now. N-channel MOSFETs turn on when V<sub>GS</sub> is positive; P-channel MOSFETs turn on when V<sub>GS</sub> is negative.

Otherwise, your schematic looks fine. But as others have already pointed out, the fact that the two elements share ground should not be an issue in the first place. You could eliminate Q1 altogether.

Comment: Okay, I see. I guess I missed that because I was so focused on trying to isolate the ground potential. I'll also try it without Q1 as soon as all the parts are here! Thanks for your help! :)